# Simplifying square roots?

Tags: factoring, radicals, prime-factorization

How would I simplify $\sqrt{\frac{800}{3}}$ preferably by a factor tree? I know it simplifies into $\frac{20\sqrt{6}}{3}$. I just don't know the steps to get there. Help please?

Comment: Note that I edited your post with proper latex. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to see how that was done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use these instructions whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\sqrt{\frac{800}{3}}=\sqrt{20^2\frac{2}{3}}=20\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=20\sqrt{\frac{2\times 3}{3\times 3}}=\frac{20}{3}\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: More than "hints" they are direct solution xDDD. Not offense, just is a bit hilarious that you said "hints" xD.

Comment: @Masacroso I guess there comes a point when a full answer is inevitable when providing hints.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how & why he got that answer.  I feel like it needs more explanation especially between the first and second pieces. Also, please note that the answer is  $\frac{20\sqrt{6}}{3}$, the √6 is also divided by the 3.

Comment: @Samuel Generally when you have something under the square root, you look for square factors of the number, because $\sqrt{a^2b} = a\sqrt{b}$. So in this case, $20^2\frac{2}{3} = \frac{2(400)}{3} = \frac{800}{3}$. And then the rest is easy to follow. Also, $\frac{20}{3}\sqrt{6} = \frac{20}{3}\frac{\sqrt{6}}{1} = \frac{20\sqrt{6}}{3}$.

Comment: @Samuel You are welcome!